# Can I have Scala 2.8 reference documentation offline?

Tags: scala, documentation

Is there a way to have full standard Scala library documentation off-line?

UPDATE: This is not a book/tutorial/whatever recommendation request, this is a question about how (if any way at all) exactly was the official Scala documentation meant to be installed for offline usage or where exactly was the official archive located. Both the question and the accepted answer are still relevant and have nothing to do with recommendations.

Comment: You can do it via sbaz: sbaz install <package-name>, where <package-name> is scala-devel-docs as I remember.

Comment: The accepted answer is just a link to an off-site resource - google serves to find those. But say the question isn't asking for an off-site resource... then it's overly broad. I suggest you [edit] it to ask what you think it's asking. I could get behind reopening it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use sbaz or just [download](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.8.0.final-devel-docs.tgz) it. See [Download Previous Versions](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html) page for newer releases.

Comment: As of 2013-Sep-30, the link no longer works.

Comment: I saw this page 2 days ago and now i came here to request new links. Thanks for updating. Coursera people like me need it nowadays.